# Change of variables inside conditional expectation

Tags: probability

Let $X, Y$ be random variables, $g$ be some function on $\mathbb{R}$ that is invertible.

Suppose also that we know $\mathbb{E}[g(Y)|X]$, and the goal is to find $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]$. Is this possible in closed-form? I'm aware we could do a Taylor approximation here, but what about an exact solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a Taylor approximation here. Let's denote $Z=g(Y)$ then $Y = g^{-1}(Z)$. For simplicity's sake, denote also $f(Z)=g^{-1}(Z)$ and $a(X)=E[Z|X]$.
We have
$$f(Z)=f(E[Z|X]) + \sum_{i=1}^{+ \infty}(Z-E[Z|X])^n\frac{d^n}{dz^n}f(E[Z|X])$$
$$f(Z)=f(a(X)) + \sum_{i=1}^{+ \infty}(Z-E[Z|X])^n\frac{d^n}{dz^n}f(a(X))$$
This implies that
$$E[Y|X]=E[f(Z)|X] = f(a(X)) + \sum_{i=1}^{+ \infty}E[(Z-a(X))^n |X]\frac{d^n}{dz^n}f(a(X))$$
But if you know only $E[Z|X]$ and not the variable $Z$ (or $Y$) itself, the term $E[(Z-a(X))^n|X] = E[(g(Y)-a(X))^n|X]$ is undefined.

The conclusion: it is unable to determine $E[Y|X]$ from the sole information $E[g(Y)|X]$.

Comment: What if $g$ isn't differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

The conditioning on $X$ is immaterial here; the question boils down to

> If I know $E[g(Y)]$ can I determine $E[Y]$?

Since $g$ is invertible, the question further reduces to

> If I know $E[Y]$, can I determine $E[f(Y)]$ where $f$ is invertible?

This is not true: for exapmle there are many zero-mean random variables $Y$ such that $E[f(Y)]$ are different.

(Take for instance $Y_n / n \sim \text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ and $f(x) = e^x$. Then $E[Y_n] = 0$ for all $n$, but  $E[f(Y_n)] = \frac{e^n + e^{-n}}{2}$ which depends on $n$.)